# Angular scope object not update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a written an Angular module for translation. And this module is successfully working with two of our applications but not working with new application.

Our new application controller is like this -

```
var app2 = angular.module("test", ["ngCookies", "Tranlater"]);

app2.controller("company", function ($scope, $cookies, $rootScope, translationService)            {

    $rootScope.currentLanguage = $cookies.SelectedLanguage;
    translationService.getTranslation($rootScope.currentLanguage, function (data) {
        $scope.translation = data;
    });
});
```

and i try to access this translation object in our view as

```
{{translation.ChooseCompany}}
```

as in our other application.
**but it's not displaying any value :(**

But when i check the scope with angular debugger console it display the values for **$scope.translation** object
[image]

Translation Service:

```
    this.getTranslation = function (language, callback) {
    if (language === undefined) {
        language = "en";
    }
    var languageFilePath = '/translation_' + language + '.json';
    if (!me.cache[language]) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: languageFilePath,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                me.cache[language] = data;
                if (typeof callback === "function")
                    callback(me.cache[language]);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        if (typeof callback === "function")
            callback(me.cache[language]);
    }
};
```

Comment: We'd need to see the code from `translationService` to tell you why. My guess is the callback is manually fired without a `$scope.$apply` or similar

Comment: do you have value for $rootScope.currentLanguage?

Comment: I update the question with Translation service

Comment: $scope.$apply(); work :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the $scope.$apply();

```
$rootScope.currentLanguage = $cookies.SelectedLanguage;
translationService.getTranslation($rootScope.currentLanguage, function (data) {
    $scope.translation = data;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

this is the solution